# Heroku says attribute exists that doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I just successfully deployed, and run a migration. Now I see this error.

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError (update is defined by Active Record):
app/controllers/project_updates_controller.rb:4:in `new'
```

I used to have an attribute in my Project_Updates called "update", but the migration renamed it to "description" so that should not be a problem anymore. To make sure that the migration did in fact rename the column I tried to make a new ProjectUpdate as so:

```
irb(main):001:0> @projectUpdate = ProjectUpdate.new
=> #<ProjectUpdate id: nil, description: nil, project_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, deleted_at: nil, featured_image_id: nil, title: nil>
```

As you can see, there is no "update" method, but there is a "description" method, so it did rename properly.

Why am I still getting this Dangerous Attribute error? P.S. this is only on production, not dev.

**SOLVED**

It looks like my db/schema might have been incorrect. I pulled from heroku, deleted my scheme, ran db:migrate, then pushed, and this solved the problem.

Comment: Show your `project_updates_controller` and `project_updates` form.

Comment: Never post information as images. You get a down vote for that, ping me when you fix it so I can remove it.

Comment: The error is in `project_updates_controller.rb` line 4?

Comment: Michal, I removed the images. I thought those would be more helpful than the text, but apparently not. Now I know not to post images on the stackoverflow community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is basically caused by `update` being a pre-defined `ActiveRecord` method. This basically means if you call `@x.update`, it's a pre-defined method & will throw an error. The `DangerousAttributeError` is described in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DangerousAttributeError.html) as thus:

> Raised when attribute has a name reserved by Active Record (when
>   attribute has name of one of Active Record instance methods).

--

**Fix**

You've fixed the `db` with a migration, however, it seems your `project_updates_controller` is still referencing the `update` "attribute" somewhere. It mentions it's on `line 4` (in the `new` action)

To fix it, you should change the action to reference `description` instead of `update`

Comment: Yes I knew that update was causing the problem, that's why I changed it to description. You're right it was not referencing description. My question was why? I did a migration and it should have referenced it fine.

I was able to solve this problem, by pulling from heroku, deleting my schema, re-migrating, then pushing the new schema. There must have been an issue in the schema.